# Finding the kernel of a homomorphism

Tags: group-theory

I have the groups of nonzero complex numbers and the positive real numbers and the homomorphism $f: \Bbb{C}^{*} \to \Bbb{R}_+$ such that $f(z)= \lvert z \rvert$. I need to find the kernel of f.

Now... $\ker(f)=\{f(z)=0\}$. I know that if $z=a+bi$, then $|z|= \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ which is $0$ only if $a=b=0$, but then $z$ will also be $0$. What am I missing?

**[EDIT]**
Yes, silly me... my kernel was wrong, it should be $Ker(f)=${${\forall z \in C^*| f(z)=e=1}$}. Thank you all. Delete the question, maybe?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Comment: becuase you define f form nonezero complex numbers to positive real numbers kernel of f will be {} becuase0 is not at f domain

Comment: I have fixed (most of) the maths typesetting, but as noted in the answers, you should fix your kernel.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks; Silviya, please look at how he typeset the mathematics so that you may learn from it.

Comment: @Lord_Farin, I did and I also looked at the links you gave me. Thank you and thank Andreas Caranti too.

Comment: Nice, we appreciate that! No need to delete the question btw. It may help out others having the same issue :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of $f$ is the set $\{z \mid f(z) = e\}$, where $e$ is the identity of $\Bbb R_{>0}$.

Now note that $\Bbb R_{>0}$ is a *multiplicative* group.

---

Further hint: So $e$ is a number satisfying $e \cdot x = x = x \cdot e$ for all $x \in \Bbb R_{>0}$...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The positive real numbers are a group under what operation?  What is the identity element?